# Calling SDL_SetVideoMode several times

Tags: c++, sdl, surface

Is it ok to do the following?

```
SDL_Surface* screen;
screen = SDL_SetVideoMode( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_BPP, SDL_SWSURFACE | SDL_RESIZABLE | SDL_FULLSCREEN );
screen = SDL_SetVideoMode( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_BPP, SDL_SWSURFACE | SDL_RESIZABLE );
screen = SDL_SetVideoMode( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_BPP, SDL_SWSURFACE | SDL_RESIZABLE | SDL_FULLSCREEN );
```

I don't need to clean up the surface before each call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to toggle fullscreen on Windows is to call SDL_SetVideoMode again. You have not to free the screen surface.

Be careful, you may lost the hardware surfaces.